# Fantasy/sci-fi book about a boy who travels to space and learns to manipulate metal

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens, spaceship

Book is about a boy who travels to space and learns to manipulate metal.

He gets a few friends one of them dies from an alien prisoner, I think her name was Kate.

They go to a planet where barely any women live and are used as a leverage to allow humans to continue digging up the metal that they can manipulate.

The aliens live in 9 circles?

There is a creature that is called a centurion?

- I think it is basically a landmass that has lived for a long time and has transformed into something else.

The main character falls in love with a girl who is a leader of one of the groups.

Please help!!

Comment: Welcome to the site. When did you read this book, and roughly when do you think it might've been published?

Comment: i read it around 2016 - 2020, most likely would've been published around the early 2000's or maybe 2010